# How to tell what class is calling a method in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I have this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments

  before_save :save_outstanding_amount

  def save_outstanding_amount # atomic saving
    self.outstanding_amount = new_outstanding_amount
  end

  def update_outstanding_amount # adds another SQL query
    update_column(:outstanding_amount, new_outstanding_amount)
  end

  private

    def new_outstanding_amount    
      total - payments.sum(&:amount)
    end

end
```

How can make this dynamic, so that the first method gets called from all instances of the `Invoice` class and the second method gets called from all instances of other classes, e.g. the `Payment` class?

Comment: why same name for the methods, why not different names as the actions are different...

Comment: Then you should place version B in the `Payment` model...

Comment: @amitkarsale: OK, I renamed them.

Comment: @AmitThawait: But I don't have a private method `new_outstanding_amount` there.

Comment: OK, got it. Since the two methods in fact do two different things, it makes sense to give different names to them. I think the code I have above now is the solution to my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something very dangerous here. Make sure use sql to change the value instead of setting a new value.

Imagine the following:
Invoice amount: 1000
User1 deducts 100, but does it with a very slow request.
Right after user 1 starts, User2 deducts 500, and does it really quickly.

Since you're doing this stuff within the application, you end up with an outstanding amount of 900, since that's the last executed method. update_counters creates a 'safe' sql query.

```
self.class.update_counters self.id, payments.sum(&:amount)
```

This also solves your question on how to call them from two classes. Always update those columns like this.